# Disable xdebug without using commandline or edit php.ini

Tags: php, openshift, xdebug, openshift-3

Using openshift.com, but when a function runs it says

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Then I found out, that it can be fixed by turning xdebug off or changing it in the config, but openshift do not give that permission.

Is there another way to disable xdebug?

Comment: XDebug wouldn't normally be enabled on a production system anyway, so are you sure that's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can disable it for document root by adding following line to .htaccess file in doc root.

```
php_value xdebug.remote_enable 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only stops the debugging features being accessed, but they still have an effect on PHP because of the way they inject themselves into the running engine, so it's not a sure way of removing the possibility that the "max nesting" error is XDebug's fault (although I suspect it isn't anyway).